# Is my PCA code written in Python correct?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pca

I'm doing a research that demands a PCA plot, so I can see the agglomeration patterns of the plots thanks to the dimension reduction that PCA provides. So, I found a code and wanted to be sure that it does what it is supposed to do: a PCA plot. The thing is, I don't know if the code is 100% correct, because I think that for PCA to work, we first need no standardize the data so that the mean of the values for each dimension is 0, and I couldn't identificate that in the code. I'm writing this in hope to find someone that have experience doing PCA to enlighten me. Thanks, here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('B0.txt', 'r') as simulation_data:
    simulation_data = [x.strip() for x in simulation_data if x.strip()]

    data = [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in simulation_data[2:]]  

    x = [x[1] for x in data]
    y = [x[2] for x in data]
    z = [x[3] for x in data]
    mx = [x[4] for x in data]
    my = [x[5] for x in data]
    mz = [x[6] for x in data]


dados = np.array([x, y, z, mx, my, mz])


matriz_cov = np.cov(dados)


v, w = np.linalg.eig(matriz_cov)

ordem = v.argsort()

maiorautovetor = w[:, ordem[-1]]
segundomaiorautovetor = w[:, ordem[-2]]     

Wpca = np.array([maiorautovetor, segundomaiorautovetor])

novos_dados = np.dot(Wpca, dados)

plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(novos_dados[0, :], novos_dados[1, :])
plt.show()

print(maiorautovetor)
print(segundomaiorautovetor)
```

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend using an existing package to do PCA. [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA) is a good option.

Comment: Can you specify why? Because I reaIly want to understand how PCA works and I think that this code covers what a PCA should do. 1 - Arrange the data into an array; 2 - Create a covariance matrix; 3 - Find the largest eigenvectors associated to the largest eigenvalues of the covariance matrix; 4 - Project the original data into the eigenvectors space. My doubt was about standardizing the data

Comment: I'd recommend it for the same reason we use any code written by other people: it's often  better in many ways. Your question suggests this is for some research, for which correctness is probably the most important feature. But if your goal is really to _understand_ PCA, then yes, implementing it yourself can be great! Centering the data is important in PCA, but you can see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/94721320b1e13fd60046dc8bd0d343c54c2dd2e9/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2449) that it's handled when you compute the covariance matrix.

Comment: Well, thank you for your time, it really helped me